# Sending and receiving data from a ble device over android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am interfacing a BLE pedometer to an android phone. i have discovered the ble device and able to connect to it. I am sending 20 byte data to ble but
how can i check that ble is able to receive data.

```
public  void writeDataToPedometer(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside Thread's catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BluetoothGattService mGattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_PEDOMETER_SERVICE);
        mtransmitData = new TransmitData();
        if(mGattService == null) {
           Log.e("YHService", "SEND UUID Service not found");
        } else {
           BluetoothGattCharacteristic characterstic = mGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000ffb2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
           if(characterstic == null) {
              Log.e("YHService", "SET_TIME characterstic not found");
           } else {

             byte command[] = new byte[20]; 
             command[0] = 42;
             command[1] = 41;
             command[2] = 54;
             command[3] = 54;
             command[4] = 45 ;
             command[5] = 52 ;
             command[6] = 59 ;

             for (int i = 7 ;i < 20 ; i++ )
                 command[i] = 0x00;

              characterstic.setValue(command);

              try {
                 Thread.sleep(500L);
              } catch (InterruptedException var9) {
                  Log.d("Service", "Inside Catch");
                 var9.printStackTrace();
              }

              mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characterstic);
              setRecieverNotify(mGattService);
              setCharacteristicNotification(characterstic, true);

           }
        }
     }
```

I am using above function to Send data to ble device.Is above function OK for sending data or I should made some modification in it.

Where should i look for a reply from pedometer. is there any Function which will get called when pedometer will send data.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this callBack:
`public final BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
 @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)
        { 
          if(status==BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
            {                                                                          //this callback gets called after a successful write operation is performed
            }
        }
}`